# How to recover data from previous sessions in a CD or DVD

Tags: data-recovery, software-rec

A friend handed my a DVD supposedly having a backup of his kids photos and videos.
The DVD shows as empty in Windows 7, but I can see that data was burned in the disk.

**Is there a utility to explore all the disk and try to restore the data available?**

I've searched but the most of the tools focus on scratched disk. Not the problem here.

Comment: It would **really** help to know what software he used to make the backup. The format may be proprietary and need special software to read.

Comment: @ChrisS: ok, I'll find out (probably tomorrow because was copied in a PC shop, ironically)

Comment: what do you mean, you can "see" data was burned to the disc?

Comment: @ChrisS: Aren't all files burned in a standard way so all drives can read them?

Comment: @wizlog: The different shade in the tracks...

Comment: @EduardoMolteni Yes, all CDs are burned in a standard data format. That doesn't mean they all have the same file system. CDs are just like any storage medium, they hold 1s and 0s, but have a file system to make sense of files and folders. Most CDs use ISO 9660 or one of its extensions, some use UDF; but the CD could contain any other file system and possibly just raw data (not terribly uncommon in the *nix world to write a tar file straight to disc). These are uncommon, but so is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that somewhere there is free software that would do this for you, however as of now, I can't find any.

[DiskInternals CD & DVD Recovery](http://www.diskinternals.com/cd-dvd-recovery/) offers a trial that allows you to test for files on your CD/DVD. You may need to purchase the program to receive full functionality.

(if it doesn't work, you can try [Discgetor](http://www.diskgetor.com/cd-dvd-recovery.htm).)

Additionally, it may help if you installed the backup utility on the computer that shows a blank disc.

You didn't specify an operating system in your question, so I'll assume your using Windows. If you burned the disc on Windows 7, it might not be readable in versions of pre Windows XP. )

Comment: IsoBuster didn't find any files. I'm having more luck with Disk Internals Cd & Dvd Recovery. Developing...

Comment: @EduardoMolteni OK, I edited my answer to better address your actions.

Answer (score 1):

I recover the files using [Disk Internals Cd & Dvd Recovery](http://www.diskinternals.com/cd-dvd-recovery/) It's $40, but wasn't on me :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can see **physically burned sectors** on the DVD that are not present when you mount the media, could be due to a previous burned session, already closed and not visible now, or to data deliberately placed in non-indexed sectors, or simply   the result of a bad burn. Some security options allowed to reburn *deleted* sector with data when you *delete* data from a CD/DVD.

Under Linux there are many tools, some of which are also available in Windows.
You can read many pages on internet; among the others  e.g. from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15827/recovering-files-from-a-corrupt-cd-dvd) answers<sup>~[[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/15839/196535),[2](https://askubuntu.com/a/656119/196535)]</sup> you can read:

- [dvdisaster](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dvdisaster)

  > Really good if you like graphical tools. It's tricky to use with commercial movie dvd's, though. You'll have to open the dvd in Totem once first to "authenticate" the drive. After that, it works well.
- [ddrescue](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ddrescue) from command line.
- foremost or testdisk to dump the image of the disk and from it to extract the files...
- [safecopy](http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/)

  > safecopy is a data recovery tool which tries to extract as much data as possible from a problematic (i.e. damaged sectors) source - like floppy drives, hard disk partitions, CDs, tape devices, ..., where other tools like dd would fail due to I/O errors.

Even some graphical tool may be able to read the previous session, you can try with the evolving [K3b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3b) or with others. Under Windows [Nero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero_Burning_ROM) was able to dump the entire media byte by byte, and possibly to browse previous sessions.