# Recover Data from a Re-writable CD/DVD

Tags: data-recovery, dvd, file-recovery, cd

I have a re-writable CD/DVD that had a priceless (to me) document on it. When I went to copy the document it was not there. Instead there were three photos of my brother.

I am guessing that due to the re-writable nature of the disk, the disk was overwritten with the photos.

I am wondering if there is any way to recover my document?

Comment: I can't remember the utility I used to use to look at the disks (it have been many years).  There is a SMALL chance that your disk has more than one written track on it.  In the early days of CD/RW, I recall many cd-writing apps that would re-write the volume descriptor but not overwrite the existing data if the CD/RW had enough space to house the new re-write of the ISO.  Your chances are low.  Finding an app like I speak of is probably also low and might have better luck with a Linux machine as they generally give access to the raw disk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover data from previous sessions in a CD or DVD](https://superuser.com/questions/369224/how-to-recover-data-from-previous-sessions-in-a-cd-or-dvd)

Comment: I'd look into ISOBuster and if no luck, talk to the guy who wrote it.